# MPAndroidChart Line graph, line gets cut inbetween

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]I have implemented Line chart and it is working perfectly. But for some values the line is not visible or its cut. I have attached the screenshot. 
For value such as `[Entry, x: 0.0 y: 0.0, Entry, x: 1.0 y: 0.0, Entry, x: 2.0 y: 0.0, Entry, x: 3.0 y: 0.0, Entry, x: 4.0 y: 1.0, Entry, x: 5.0 y: 2.0, Entry, x: 6.0 y: 3.0]` Is this issue with the Library ? As I have observed when the value changes from 0 to some greater value or from greater value to 0 line is cut.

```
LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
lineChart.setDrawBorders(true);
lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
lineChart.fitScreen();
lineChart.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
lineChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

lineChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true);

lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(true);
lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
lineChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

lineChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(true);
lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
lineChart.setScaleMinima(3f, 0f);
lineChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //set whatever color you prefer
lineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
lineChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
lineChart.setPinchZoom(false);
Legend l = lineChart.getLegend();
l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
l.setDrawInside(true);
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();

ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("1"), 5));
values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("2"), 2));
values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("3"), 6));
values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("4"), 8));
values.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat("5"), 2));

LineDataSet d = new LineDataSet(values, "Actual kWh");
    d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    d.setLineWidth(1.5f);
    d.setCircleRadius(3f);
    d.setCircleColorHole(Color.BLACK);
    d.setValueTextSize(0f);
    d.setCircleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.blue_line));
    d.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.blue_line));
    d.setDrawFilled(true);
    d.setFillDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.graph_fill));
    dataSets.add(d);
LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
lineChart.setData(data);
lineChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: why don't you try simply `values.add(new Entry(xval,yval));'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is related to `d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);`.
The negative values are cut by your graph, and the Bezier interpolation creates a curve line that has little negative values between T and W.

Please try using a different mode (like a linear one `d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR);`) or accept negative values (removing `lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true);`).

**UPDATE**

With the mode `LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER` you can obtain the desired behaviour.

Comment: I removed lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(true); but still its cut. But if I set to d.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.LINEAR); it works fine. But my requirement i to have cubic design. Is there any other option ?

Comment: Then just use the LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER and set a small negative value as the minimum Y value in this way: lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(-0.5);

Comment: There is a new feature to achieve what you're looking for: use LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1673)

Comment: @dalla92 Oh I dont have any idea about this feature. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following:

```
 lineChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);
 lineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue("yourFloatValue");
```

Your float value should be less than the minimum value of your graph. Adjust that in a way that your graph shows the curve because of Cubic bezier behavior.

Comment: hi.This works when I give -50 as axisminvalue. But this will also shift the graph.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me: `chartView.axisLeft.axisMinimum = -0.01f`

Answer (score 0):

you can set:

```
lineChart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = -0.01f
lineChart.axisLeft.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return ceil(value.toDouble()).toInt().toString()
    }
}
```